# Merge two columns in R while replacing when value is not present in other column

Tags: r

i want to merge two columns of my data set, The nature of these two columns are either/or, i.e if a value is present in one column it wont be present in other column.
i tried these

```
temp<-list(a=1:3,b=10:14)
paste(temp$a,temp$b)
```

output

```
"1 10" "2 11" "3 12" "1 13" "2 14"
```

and this

```
 temp<-list(a=1:3,b=10:14,c=20:25)
 temp<-within(temp,a <- paste(a, b, sep=''))
```

output

```
temp$a
[1] "110" "211" "312" "113" "214"
```

but what i am looking for is to replace the values when they are not present . for example temp`$`a only have 1:3 and `temp`$b have 10:14 , i.e two extra values - so i want my answer to be

```
1_10 2_11 3_12 _13 _14
```

**EDIT** -please look that i do not want column `c` to be concatenated with `a` and `$b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `stri_list2matrix`, we can `fill` the list elements that have shorter length with `''` and use `paste`.

```
library(stringi)
do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(stri_list2matrix(temp, fill='')), sep='_'))
#[1] "1_10" "2_11" "3_12" "_13"  "_14"
```

`stri_list2matrix(temp, fill='')` converts the `list` to `matrix` after filling the list elements that are shorter in `length` with `''`.  Convert it to `data.frame` (`as.data.frame`)  and use `do.call(paste` to `paste` the elements in each row separated  by `_` (`sep='_'`).

#### Update

Based on the edited 'temp', if you are interested only in the first two elements of 'temp'

```
 do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(stri_list2matrix(temp[1:2], fill='')),
         sep='_'))
 #[1] "1_10" "2_11" "3_12" "_13"  "_14"
```

You can also subset by the `names` ie. `temp[c('a', 'b')]`

Comment: @SubhamTripathi I added some description.  Hope it helps.  You can split the code into smaller chunks and check the output.

Comment: the solution that you proposed concatenates all the columns present in data frame, but what i need is i want to concatenate only two specific columns from the dataset, say in temp there are three columns a,b,c and i want to concatenate only a,b . How to do that. 

P.s: i accept my question lacked the detail :)

Comment: @SubhamTripathi  You can subset the columns in the dataset. ie. `do.call(paste, c(dat[c('a', 'b')], sep="_")`  But, you mentioned in the post that you have a `list` with 2 unequal lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the length of the shorter vector to match the length of the longer vector, then paste:

```
paste(c(temp$a,rep("",length(temp$b)-length(temp$a))), temp$b, sep="_")
#[1] "1_10" "2_11" "3_12" "_13"  "_14"
```